# How to read properties files inside WEB-INF?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I'm trying to read a configuration files which I put under /WEB-INF/config folder. The reason is that the Jetty Maven plugin [does not support resource filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475811/how-to-filter-resources-when-using-maven-jetty-plugin). Can some one please explain me how to do that using Spring Java configuration feature ?

I know that `<context: property-placeholder ... />` should work, but i dont want to use XML.

**application dirs**

```
├───META-INF
└───WEB-INF
    ├───classes
    ├───config
    ├───i18n
    ├───lib
    ├───pages
    └───resources
```

**property sources configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("log4j.properties"),
    @PropertySource("general.properties") }
)
public class ApplicationContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertySources = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Resource[] resources = new ServletContextResource[] {
                        new ServletContextResource(servletContext, "WEB-INF/config/log4j.properties"),
                        new ServletContextResource(servletContext, "WEB-INF/config/general.properties")
        };
        propertySources.setLocations(resources);
        propertySources.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return propertySources;
    }
}
```

**exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve ServletContextResource without ServletContext
```

Comment: just add it as a `@PropertySource`.

Comment: The problem is in the wiring of the servlet context.

Comment: No it isn't... You need to remove the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. As mentioned add them ad `@PropertSource`.

Comment: @PropertySource("classpath:WEB-INF/config/log4j.properties" and    @PropertySource("/WEB-INF/config/log4j.properties" not working both.

Answer (score 2):

As @M.Deinum said, there is no need to configure `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` manually: Spring Boot has `PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration` to get deal with that.

Everything what you need is `@PropertySource`.

Since your `general.properties` is located in the `ServletContext` it should be like this:

```
@PropertySource("/WEB-INF/config/general.properties")
```

Note, it does not make sence to do the same for `log4j.properties`. Consider to move it to the `/WEB-INF/classes` to allow for log4j to pick up it automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Use following lines of code with `@Autowired` Annotation.

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;
String filePath = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/XXXX/");
File file = new File(filePath );
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
```